Homemade Darlington for NEMA 23 motor
I'm demonstrating the recycling of e-waste to my local community by mining and recycling parts from entertainment equipment found in thrift stores.
As such, PNP transistors are very hard to come by. I have plenty of small signal and power npn bjt transistors available, though.
Ive studied H-Bridge circuits and understand that while a homemade Darlington such as a 2N2222A-2N3055 is inferior to a N-mosfet, it's what I have without buying additional parts.  It's all a matter of principle to me, please honor that.
Can someone provide appropriate resistor and capacitor values for these homemade Darlingtons for a dual H-bridge to step a NEMA23 motor with a 12 volt supply? That's the most motor I'd want to use.
Thank you for any help!

There's an EESE discussion on the topic from a couple years back. May be worth a read. There's also this commonly referenced youtube video illustrating one of the methods mentioned in one of the answers of the above EESE reference I just gave. Without optos, bootstrapping might be worth the trouble and could use parts you have. There are more ways, as well. But the first question is whether or not you can find/use optos. That may be easier to consider.

I like it, I like it! Ty.

Are you a hobbyist making things for yourself or for sale?

Neither. I'm an artist making kinetic sculpture
